# Addon to Google Reader for "popular posts"?

Tags: google-reader

I heard there is an addon for Google Reader that marks popular posts in the feeds to read. Does anyone know which addon that is?

Because I don't want to read every single post but just the popular ones.

Answer (score 1):

**[Google Reader Play](http://www.google.com/reader/play/)** cycles through some of the most popular content of the day. It's not within the usual Google Reader interface, but it might be what you're looking for.